# python remove unknown text inside specific mark

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this text
`text = "{\g1}Hello world!{\i6}"`
I want to remove the curly brackets and the text inside them without knowing what is inside the curly brackets,
I know how to remove a specific text by using `.replace("Hello", "Hi")`
(sorry for my English)

Comment:  http://regular-expressions.info

Comment: try `text.partition('}')[2].partition('{')[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [regular expressions](https://regexr.com/) to find & replace a particular pattern of characters.

In this case, a suitable regex pattern would be `{\\.{2}}`.

- `{` matches a "{" character
- `\\` matches a "\" character
- `.` matches any character except line breaks
- `{2}` match exactly 2 of the preceding token (`.` in this case)
- `}` matches a "}" character

So your python script would be:

```py
import re

PATTERN = r'{\\.{2}}'

text = '{\g1}Hello world!{\i6}'

clean_text = re.sub(PATTERN, '', text)

print(clean_text)
```

And it would produce the output:

```text
Hello world!
```